# VSCode .Net Core MVC reports problems but Project Builds and Runs just fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have been using VSCode on OSX to develop a .Net Core Web MVC app.   I can build and run the app using dotnet build cmd.  No errors are reported when built.   But today I opened VSCode and I am getting 100's of VSCode Problems reported by the C# extension.  I can't figure out how to reset or solve this issue.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: I created a new .Net Core MVC project using dotnet new mvc. I opened the project in vscode with no modifications. VSCode immediately showed the errors/problems. I opened this new project in VSCode on Windows. No errors.
On VSCode OSX I removed the C# extension and the errors disappeared.   I reinstalled the C# extension and the errors returned.

Comment: If you close VSCode, check task manager for any remaining OmniSharp processes, kill them, and reopen, does the problem persist?

Comment: I've had this happen when I move files around into different folders. Do what @jdoer1997 says and also remove the binaries

Comment: @jdoer1997 As stated I am on OSX, not windows so no Task Manger.   I did however reboot my PC.  The problem still persists.  I also deleted the files in the bin directory.   Still the errors are shown in the Problems tab.   I can build and run the project without any errors.

Comment: I have the same issue too!

Comment: UPDATE:   I created a new .Net Core MVC project using dotnet new mvc.  I opened the project in vscode with no modifications.   VSCode immediately showed the errors/problems.   I opened this new project in VSCode on Windows.   No errors.

Comment: I'd check OmniSharp Log in output tab in VSCode. Might find there's a bunch of error messages you search the net for to find resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
{    
  "omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "never"
}
```

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4134#issuecomment-714326240

Answer (score -1):

If you have just installed something try to restart your PC.